# PL/SQL: can't insert into a temporary tables

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm not really sure whats wrong with this error. The error occurred at the INSERT INTO statement below. I was trying to insert the values from the cursor loop above into a temporary table. The error was 'SQL Statement ignored'

````
PROCEDURE loopHalfHourIntervals AS
sourceDay DATE;
sourceDayName VARCHAR2(10);
sourceInterval NUMBER(3);
sourceVolume FLOAT(20);
    CURSOR c_findValues IS
    SELECT DAY, hh, volume
    FROM V_NEM_RM16;
    BEGIN
    --FOR r_findValues IN c_findValues
        OPEN c_findValues;
        LOOP
        FETCH c_findValues INTO sourceDay, sourceInterval, sourceVolume;
            IF identifyHoliday(sourceDay) = TRUE
            THEN  sourceDayName := 'HOLIDAY';
            ELSE sourceDayName := trim(to_char(to_date(sourceDay, 'DD-MON-YYYY'),'day'));
            END IF;
       INSERT INTO tmpForecast --error occurred here
            (
                currentDay,
                dayInterval,
                volume
                            )
        VALUES
            (
                UPPPER(sourceDayName),
                sourceInterval,
                sourceVolume
                            ); 
        EXIT WHEN c_findValues%notfound;
        END LOOP;
        common.log('Holidays check completed and stored in tmp_forecast');
END loopHalfHourIntervals; ```
````

[image: error image]

Comment: Is this a function or procedure or anonymous block?

Comment: it is a procedure

Comment: please show the complete error message including the ORA error

Comment: I have added a screen shot of the error

Comment: `UPPPER` should be `UPPER`.

Comment: Thanks Arun thats fixed it. My eyes are so tired right now couldnt even see it